# OpenCV with Code::Blocks

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks with the library OpenCV 
I wrote the following code

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc)
{
 src = imread( argc[1], 1 );
 cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
 return 0;
 }
```

When I run the code the following window appear
what is the solution to the problem :(
[image]

Comment: This code should not even compile, as you have not declared the type of `src`. I am guessing that line should say `Mat src = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the correct libraries: [Howto use libraries with Code::Blocks](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)